# Symfony - form event - get new and old data

Tags: php, symfony

I have a `Post` entity and `PostType`.

Post entity have field `$requireModeration` it means someone must check this post and approve it before it can be published.

When I'm editing post I want to compare old post value and new post value. And if value is changed I also want to change `requireModeration` flag to true.

Can I do it through form events?
Something like this:

```
public function postSubmit(FormEvent $event)
{
    $newPost = $event->getData();
    $newContent = $post->getContent(); // return new contant of post
    $oldPost = ... // here I want to get old post
    $oldContent = $oldPost->getContent();

    if($newContent != $oldContent) {
        // ...
    }
}
```

But unfortunately I can get only new, just sent data through FormEvent object.

Comment: You will need to keep track of the entity object that you use to pre populate the form fields with to compare the new & old. The form event will not have any record of previous data when you post the new data.

Answer (score 3):

You should use Doctrine's lifecycle events and `UnitOfWork` for this instead of Form events (I assume that you use `Doctrine` at your project).

Add `preUpdate` listener to your `Post` entity and do something like:

```
$uow = $em->getUnitOfWork();
$changeset = $uow->getEntityChangeSet($entity);
```

In `$changeset` variable you will have fields list that was changed in the `$entity` during current request with their old and new values.

Comment: Mhm. And if I change `requireModeration` how can I put it back into my entity?

Comment: You just call $entity->setRequireModeration(true); in the listener

Answer (score 3):

```
public function postSubmit(FormEvent $event)
{
    $newPost = $event->getData();
    $newContent = $newPost->getContent();
    $uow = $this->em->getUnitOfWork();
    $oldPost = $uow->getOriginalEntityData($post);
    $oldContent = $OriginalEntityData["content"];

    if($newContent != $oldContent) {
        // ...
    }
}
```